# Retrieve Trusted Platform Module(TPM 2.0) EKPub

Tags: azure, tpm

I am trying to add a TPM 2.0 enabled device to Azure Device Provisioning Service Enrollment List. This requires the Endorsement Key (EKPub) of the TPM. 
What would be the best way to extract (find out) the EKPub (Endorsment Key) of a TPM? I appreciate your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535281/interpreting-tpm-tools-tpm-getpubek-output

Answer (score 0):

Intel provide a suite of tools for interacting with a TPM 2.0 which you can download from here: https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools

Note you'll have to also compile and install abrmd (a resource manager) and the tss stack/libraries. The tools work on Linux (Ubuntu, RedHat, CentOS, Debian at least, and Raspian on the Raspberry PI with a suitable TPM board).

The command you're looking for here is:  tpm2_createek  which will generate the EK and store it in the TPM. Meaning, that the TPM 2.0 has a seed value from which the EK (and AK) is generated when needed. Typically - at least we do - is generate the EK and AK, then move these to persistent handles so they survive power down.

https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_createek.1.md

Comment: tpm2_getekcertificate is maybe more appropriate?!

Comment: Which is part of the tpm2_tools tool set.  If you just want the public key then createek is the command. The EKcert however should be in one of the NVRAM locations - tpm2_getekcertificate is a convenience tool for obtaining that.